# Why is gradle creating a "java" directory under build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I created a new Gradle project using gradle init. I've changed very few default properties. For an older project, classes are going to [project-dir]/build/classes, but in my new project, with a very similar build.gradle file, classes are going to [project-dir]/build/**java**/classes. The property for buildDir is [project-dir]/build. So where is [project-dir]/build/**java** coming from? I think that's causing me problems with the class loader.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/release-notes.html#location-of-classes-in-the-build-directory, https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/release-notes.html#build-cache-improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Nizet beat me to it with the link)

In the major number release Gradle 4 they allowed themselves to change the build directory to support multiple JVM languages. It was announced prior to the release.

> Cache-safe mixed JVM language compilation In Gradle 3.5, projects that
>   used both Java and another JVM language (like Groovy or Scala) would
>   encounter problems when using the build cache. The class files created
>   by multiple compilation tasks were all placed into the same output
>   directory, which made determining the set of outputs to cache for each
>   task difficult and would cause Gradle to cache the wrong outputs for
>   each compilation task.
>
> **Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language.**

So you'll have /build/java, build/scala etc.